# make subst not working as I want it to be

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to use makefile "subst" function to split the text. Here is my code.

```
$(subst :,\nvalue:,peter:value:2)
```

what I want to do is that is to split from the first of occurrence of the ':'. but it also splits on the second occurrence. Can someone help me how to solve that issue. the result she be similar to below.

```
peter\nvalue:value:2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states, the subst function replaces *every* occurrence of the original text with the new text.

If you want only the first one you'll have to get a lot more fancy, if you want to do it completely within make and you don't know anything about the text before or after the first colon.  Something like this should work:

```
VAL := peter:value:2
NEW := $(patsubst $(firstword $(subst :, ,$(VAL)))%,$(firstword $(subst :, ,$(VAL)))\nvalue%,$(VAL))
```

There might be a simpler way to do it; I'll have to think about it.

Comment: One caveat: This doesn't work if the part before the first `:` can contain a space.

Comment: Yes, very true.  In general make doesn't like whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having make invoke a shell to do this, you could do:

```
VAL := peter:value:2
NEW := $(shell echo "$(VAL)" | sed -e 's/:/\\nvalue:/')
```

I'm not sure if your `\n` is a literal "\n" or a newline.  I'm assuming the former.  This means the `\n` in the `sed` expression needs to be escaped as `\\n`.

---

Another way of doing it completely within make (without any shell invocations):

```
empty:=
space:= $(empty) $(empty)

VAL := peter:value:2
VL := $(subst :, ,$(VAL))
NEW := $(firstword $(VL))\nvalue:$(subst $(space),:,$(wordlist 2,$(words $(VL)),$(VL)))
```

Caveat: This method will give incorrect results if the original value contains whitespace.

Comment: That all-make way of doing it doesn't work correctly if there are any spaces in the original value.

Comment: @EtanReisner - very true.  I'll add that caveat to the answer.